# webpack put vendor chunk to app chunk when using with bower

Tags: webpack

webpack.config.js

```
var path = require("path");
var webpack = require("webpack");
module.exports = {
    entry: "./res/app/entry.js",
    vendor: ["jquery"],
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/res/js/",
        filename: "app.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css"}
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        root: [path.join(__dirname, "bower_components")]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ResolverPlugin(
            new webpack.ResolverPlugin.DirectoryDescriptionFilePlugin("bower.json", ["main"])
        ),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin("vendor", "vendor.bundle.js")
    ]
};
```

bower.json:

```
{
  "name": "webapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "jquery": "~1.11"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "jquery": "~1.11"
  }
}
```

After ran `webpack`, two file are generated:

```
app.js(the application chunk)

vendor.bundle.js(vendor chunk)
```

However the `jquery` is put inside the `app.js` which should be in the `vendor.bundle.js`.

Anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, the format of the `entry` is wrong, it should be :

```
entry: {
    app: "./res/app/entry.js",
    vendor: ["jquery"]
},
```